# Jetbrains (Intellij IDEA and Clion) blinking when switching tabs in fullscreen mode

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, clion

Both `Intellij IDEA` and `Clion` blink when I switch tabs under fullscreen mode. I'm using `OS X yosemite`. There are several tracks discussing on this problem in `Jetbrains` official site but none of the proposed solutions works for me. Does anyone know how to solve this? I like `Jetbrains`' IDEs a lot. But this problem is really annoying.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the bundled JDK. It happens always on my machine when I do a major update of a Jetbrain IDE.

You might try to switch the JDK version to the machines version: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under